# Rails: Access an attribute from background worker (Stripe charge_id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I managed to get Stripe working and processing Jobs, where a user must pay a one-time charge in order to create a Job record.

After putting the call to `Stripe::Charge.create` in a background job I can't manage to figure out how to pass the `charge.id` from `Stripe::Charge.create` to an Order object.

I planned to move the Order.create call into the sidekiq worker and access the `charge.id` directly, but I can't access the @job within the worker because a stripeToken can't be used more than once. Any idea on how I can still save the `charge.id` to an `Order`? *(separate from the main Job model)*

**JobsController**

```
def create
    ...

    if @job.create_with_stripe(params[:stripeToken])
      if @job.save
        Order.create(
          # Can't figure out how to pass the charge.id from StripePaymentJob
          :charge_id    => @charge.id,
          :job_id       => @job.id
        )
      end
      ...
  end
```

**Job Model**

```
def create_with_stripe(token)
    Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.stripe_secret_key

    if valid?
      StripePaymentJob.perform_later(token, SecureRandom.uuid)
    else
    ...
  end
```

**Stripe Worker**

```
class StripePaymentJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(token, idempotent_key)
    @charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
      ...
    }, { idempotency_key: idempotent_key })
  end
end
```

Comment: Removed some of the code for security reasons

Comment: Can you save the job before you call `create_with_stripe`? Sidekiq pro I think supports callbacks, but without paying for that I think you will need to re-order how some of these things are being saved. If you can save the job first you can pass the job id into the worker and then create the order in the worker.

Comment: @Jon Ah right. My problem is that I want to save the job only after Stripe has been called. Actually, I guess that a user expects to be charged _at some point_. No reason why I can't save the job and then process the charge.

Do you have any other ideas on how I can store the charge_id? I feel it's pertinent to have to retrieve past charges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider this approach:

- Before requesting the job be performed, create the order record with a nil *charge_id*
- After the Stripe transaction has been completed in the job, update the order with the returned *charge_id*

To do this, you can rely on **globalid**, which allows your job to access the order directly. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid for info.

Update your job implementation to now update the object after the job has completed successfully:

```
class StripePaymentJob < ApplicationJob  
  queue_as :default

  def perform(token, idempotent_key, order)
    @charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
      ...
    }, { idempotency_key: idempotent_key })
    order.update(charge_id: @charge.id, job_id: self.jid)
  end
end
```

Obviously you will need more logging and error handling, since this is happening in the background and you'll not know when and what fails.

Your job model will now call the perform_later as

```
order = Order.create
StripePaymentJob.perform_later(order, token, SecureRandom.uuid)
```

Let me know if this works, or if I need to update this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Phil....I'll check this out in the evening and write back.

Comment: I prefer passing the ID rather than the entire object where `ActiveJob` Globalid library does the work behind the scenes to serialize/deserialize the ActiveRecord instance. ActiveJob had an Error while trying to deserialize arguments because I have a 'UrlValidator' on the object that was being passed.